# Just did an update in 16.04 and suddenly instead of Cinnamon, I have Gnome!

Tags: gnome, updates, 16.04, cinnamon

This is the weirdest thing I've ever seen. I just installed the new 16.04 and then installed Cinnamon, which was working perfectly as far as I could tell. Today I did a "partial update" and when I rebooted, instead of having a couple options for Cinnamon and one for Ubuntu, I have Gnome and Ubuntu. I don't even like Gnome and would not install it myself.

What happened? Did something change that I'm unaware of? I was going to try reinstalling Cinnamon but I'm going to wait a bit and see if anyone here has useful information first. I should add that the Cinnamon files are still in my /usr folder where they always were. Is a reinstall the best way to go?

Thanks!

Comment: Remove it and  you could install a stable version again.

Comment: did you add any ppa during the installation of cinnamon?

Comment: Tried but was unable to move anything into the right folder.

Comment: Did you add this `ppa:moorkai/cinnamon`

Comment: No. I did ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon

Comment: try to purge this `sudo ppa-purge ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon`

Comment: try this : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:moorkai/cinnamon    

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cinnamon`

Comment: First I tried 'sudo ppa-purge ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon' and I got the following message: 'sudo: ppa-purge: command not found'

Comment: Then I did 'sudo apt-get purge cinnamon' This was followed by 'sudo apt autoremove' and that did the trick

Comment: you can go to synaptic package manager and then from the menu tab find repositories and find the one you added with cinnamon

Comment: Following this I tried what you wrote above and received this message: 'EDIT 4: PPA discontinued! Please switch to embrosyn's (ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon) instead.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~moorkai/+archive/ubuntu/cinnamon
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it'
I pressed enter and the install completed.

Comment: you can use also ‘sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:embrosyn/cinnamon’ from terminal

Comment: so can you get the cinnamon now and get the cinnamon desktop environment .

Comment: Just rebooted the system and tested it. It's back! I will consider the issue solved --- at least for the time being. Thanks bhordupur!

Comment: glad that you got it running